# Per Machine Install using A Standard User Account

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, admin, wix3.5

I want to know about the possibility of an per machine install using a standard user account , the installer asks me for an admin password when i want to go for a per machine install logged in as a standard user , when i put in the password it starts installing i would like to know is this an admin install or a standard user install?

Can i do something to elevate the rights of the standard user so that it does not ask for an admin password to check if a standard user could do a per machine install.

I am asking this because there are different things given on the internet and none of them have worked for me.

What if i want to an added feature in a per machine install so that the installer installs for the standard users only and not for the Admins .

I am using Wix 3.5 toolkit for making my installer.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot avoid elevating at some point. You can elevate ahead of time to "advertise" the installation, which allows a standard user later not to need to elevate (the service remembers the installation is allowed). But in order to make per-machine modifications, Windows Installer requires elevated permission.